# Django NoReverseMatch and Blank Page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am using Django 1.4.5.

I get *an error* when I access **the detail of entry via admin's page.**

> "NoReverseMatch at /admin/r/12/1/": Reverse for 'detail' with
>   arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'category': u'category',
>   'slug': u'entry-test'}' not found

And get *nothing/blank page* when access **the detail of entry on front's page** (/category/entry-test/).

And what's the right of models & URLname pattern if I want to access the entry detail via sub-category (/category/subcategory/entry-test/)?

Model snippet:

```
class Entry (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    category = models.ForeignKey('entry.Category')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('entry.views.detail', (), {'category': self.category.slug, 'slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        return super(Entry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.parent:
            return self.parent.title, self.title
        return self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('entry.views.category', (), {'slug': self.slug})
```

Views snippet:

```
def category(request):
    category = Category.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('category.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def list(request, slug_id):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug_id)
    list = Entry.objects.filter(category=category)
    return render_to_response("list.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def detail(request, category_id, slug_id):
    entry = Entry.objects.filter(slug=slug_id)
    category = Category.objects.filter(slug=category_id)
    return render_to_response('detail.html', locals(),  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

URLs snippet:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('entry.views',
    (r'^$', 'category', name='entry-category'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug_id>[-\w]+)/$', 'list', name='entry-list'),
    url(r'^(?P<category_id>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug_id>[-\w]+)/$', 'detail', name='entry-detail'),
```

Template snippet:

category.html

```
<ul>
{% for category in category %}
<li><a href="{{ category.slug }}">{{ category.title }}</a> ({{ category.entry_set.all.count }})</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

list.html

```
<ul>
{% for entry in list %}
<li><a href="{{ entry.slug }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

detail.html

```
<ul>
{% for entry in entry.category %}
<li><a href="{{ entry.category }}/{{ entry.get_absolute_url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
<br />{{ entry.description }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Where and what I could be doing wrong?
If any one can help I'd appreciate it! Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do little mistake on detail template:

```
<ul>
   {% for entry in entry %}
   <li>
      <a href="{{ entry.get_absolute_url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
      <br />
      {{ entry.description }}
   </li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The problem is solved now.

Answer (score 2):

Your keyword arguments for the url are `category_id` and `slug_id`, but you are passing in `category` and `slug` in your `get_absolute_url` method. This version should work:

```
 @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('entry.views.detail',
                (), {'category_id': self.category.slug, 'slug_id': self.slug})
```

Also consider renaming your arguments. `id` is generally numeric and `slug` is alphanumeric.

For your blank page problem (from your comment):

Your URL `/category/entry-test/` - this will map to your detail view if the snippet your pasted in your question is in your main `urls.py`. If you have no matching results (the `.filter()` call has no results), you'll see a "blank" page, because the `<ul>` will not have any `li` elements.

If in your main `urls.py`, you have something like `url('^category/', include(some.other.urls))`, then the URL will map to your `list` view, and you have the same issue - the `.filter()` is not returning any results, and hence you see a "blank" page.